# ISSUE WITH CASE and GROUP BY-WHAT KIND OF SQL TO LEARN/IDE issue?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, case, aggregate-functions

Introduction-
I am attempting to learn SQL on my own. I have been using a combination of **CODECADEMY, MODE ANALYTICS** and some youtubers as needed. I have been doing the lessons in **SQL SERVER MANAGMENT STUDIO**.

I am at a point now where I am not sure if I should stop using SQL SERVER MANAGMENT STUDIO and find something else. The tutorials are starting diverge.

CODE I wanted to use:

```
SELECT 
CASE    WHEN height = 0 THEN 'NA'             
        WHEN height <=64 THEN 'bottom_25%_for_height'
        WHEN height > 64 and height <=70 THEN 'TOP_50%_for_height'
        WHEN height > 70 and height <=76 THEN 'TOP_50%_for_height'
        ELSE 'TOP 25!'
        END AS HEIGHT_GROUPING,
        count(1) as count
FROM benn.college_football_players
GROUP BY HEIGHT_GROUPING
```

CODE it took me an hour to figure out how to use, which in no way resembles either of the guided tutorials I am using.

```
    SELECT 
CASE    WHEN height = 0 THEN 'NA'             
        WHEN height <=64 THEN 'bottom_25%_for_height'
        WHEN height > 64 and height <=70 THEN 'TOP_50%_for_height'
        WHEN height > 70 and height <=76 THEN 'TOP_25%_for_height'
        ELSE 'TOP 25!'
        END AS HEIGHT_GROUPING,
        count(1) as count
FROM benn.college
group by CASE       WHEN height = 0 THEN 'NA'             
        WHEN height <=64 THEN 'bottom_25%_for_height'
        WHEN height > 64 and height <=70 THEN 'TOP_50%_for_height'
        WHEN height > 70 and height <=76 THEN 'TOP_25%_for_height'
        ELSE 'TOP 25!'
        END
```

To be honest I am not even sure if I am just using the wrong IDE, or I'm studying the wrong version.

Also the **SQL SERVER MANAGMENT STUDIO** does not allow LIMIT, where as both of the tutorials do. Did I just pick the wrong thing? Guidance for the lost please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Differences in sql dialects is just a fact of life. SQL Server doesn't have some niceties that other dbms's do, and vice versa. You'll get a job at a place and get more proficient in the flavor of dbms they use, but translating SO answers for one dbms into something that works for yours never goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on what *Database Management Systems (DBMS)* or "**engine**" you're using. Each engine has their own dedicated syntax that you will have to learn. There's a lot of overlap between them, but also a lot of differences (like all of software development, it depends on what you're trying to accomplish, **trade-offs** are the norm, they each have their own strengths and weaknesses).

SQL Server uses `SELECT TOP(N)` to return a specific number of rows, meanwhile other popular engines like MySQL and Postgresql utilize `LIMIT N`. DB2 uses the syntax `FETCH FIRST N ROWS ONLY` for example.

So the short answer is yes, you're using the wrong engine if you're trying to use `LIMIT` in SQL Server. You can download MySQL and utilize freeware like [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) for example which is a great SQL learning tool and a good place to start your SQL journey:

> XAMPP is a completely free, easy to install Apache distribution
> containing MariaDB, PHP, and Perl.

XAMPP also comes with a administative interface (similar to SQL Server Management Studio but for MySQL vs. Microsoft SQL Server) that you can use called phpMyAdmin or you can download [MySQL Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) by Oracle:

> MySQL WorkBench is part of MySQL database and it provides a full
> featured administrative interface to execute SQL queries and MySQL
> management where as phpMyAdmin is a web based tool to administer the
> MySQL database.

Regarding your provided code. It goes back to: it depends on what exactly you're trying to accomplish and what engine you're using (and be sure to tag your appropriate engine).

I would suggest reading the following articles so you get a better understanding how things work here on Stack Overflow. You should post a specific problem ([How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) with sample data and your expected output.

[Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Be sure to post your sample data as a markdown table or in a code block and **not** as an image:

[Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

You can use websites like [TableConvert](https://tableconvert.com/) to easily create markdown tables to paste in Stack Overflow.

Another way you can test your code on multiple engines is by utilizing **Fiddles**:

[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/)
[db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)
[sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

These also come in handy for providing additional information when asking questions or checking answers to questions.